# How to validate and display form data using ES6 Javascript class

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a form that takes the users input and displays it using HTML/JS ES6.

So far, I've referenced this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/write-less-do-more-with-javascript-es6-5fd4a8e50ee2/) but am still struggling.

My exact error is [image: here] and my code is below.

My question is, what is the Uncaught Type error and how is `meeting.sessiontitle` not a function, but `meeting.date` is?

Also, any other errors in my code or better techniques I should use please let me know. I just need a nudge in the right direction and I'm positive I can take care of the rest. Thanks!

**script.js**

```
class TechClubMeeting {
  constructor(Date, sessiontitle, speaker) {
    this.Date = Date;
    this.sessiontitle = "sessiontitle";
    this.speaker = "speaker";
  }

  meetingString(){
    console.log('${this.Date},${this.sessiontitle},${this.speaker}');
  }
}

//inherit TechClubMeeting methods and properties
class NewMeeting extends TechClubMeeting{
  Date(){
    console.log(this.date)
  }
  sessiontitle(){
    console.log(this.sessiontitle)
  }
  speaker(){
    console.log(this.speaker)
  }
};

const meeting= new NewMeeting(this.Date, this.sessiontitle, this.speaker);
  meeting.Date();
  meeting.sessiontitle();
  meeting.speaker();

//display results on page
function showInput() {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML =
                document.getElementById(meeting.Date()).value;
    document.getElementById('Sessiontitle').innerHTML =
                document.getElementById(meeting.sessiontitle()).value;
    document.getElementById('Speaker').innerHTML =
                document.getElementById(meeting.speaker()).value;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tech Club Meeting Organizer</title>
  </head>
<body>

  <form>
  <div>
    <label><b>Speaker:</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="speaker">
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div>
    <label><b>Session Title:</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="sessiontitle">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><b>Date:</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="Date">
  </div>
  </form>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Add a new meeting" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <br>
  <label>Meeting Schedule: </label>
  <p><span id='display'></span></p>
  <p><span id='Sessiontitle'></span></p>
  <p><span id='Speaker'></span></p>
</body>
<script src="script.js">
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `this.sessiontitle = "sessiontitle"` overrides `function sessiontitle` - the rest of the code has too many errors to mention

Comment: `Date` is a reserved word in Javascript, as it is the name of Javascript Date objects prototype.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand your code you should read about OOP and inheritance (using new Class syntax and old Constructors) in JavaScript. I will try explaining you a little what is going on in your code.

1. `TechClubMeeting` is parent of a `NewMeeting` and you create 3 properties: `sessiontitle, speaker and Date` (don't name properties with reserved words!!! Date is a reserverd word in JS) and one method called `meetingString`.
2. If you assigned `this.sessiontitle = "sessiontitle";` in parent class every child class will have this property which is an string not a function!
3. If you create object using `new` keyword are added all properities to this object and all methods to its prototype.
4. You don't use constructor in child class so will be used parent constructor
5. When you call `new NewMeeting(this.Date, this.sessiontitle, this.speaker)` you create following object:

   ```
   NewMeeting {sessiontitle: "sessiontitle", speaker: "speaker", Date: ƒ}
    Date: ƒ Date()
    sessiontitle: "sessiontitle"
    speaker: "speaker"
     __proto__: TechClubMeeting
       Date: ƒ Date()
       constructor: class NewMeeting
       sessiontitle: ƒ sessiontitle()
       speaker: ƒ speaker()
        __proto__: Object
         ....
   ```
6. When you are try calling `meeting.sessiontitle()` you are trying calling string as a function because of javascript first meet `sessiontitle` which equals `"sessiontitle"`. This generates your error `Uncaught TypeError: meeting.sessiontitle is not a function`

**Remarks:**
When you call `new NewMeeting(this.Date, this.sessiontitle, this.speaker)` `this` refers to the global object so `this.Date` is a function which creates string with a single moment in time. `this.sessiontitle` or `this.speaker`could be html tag with `id` named `sessiontitle or speaker` or another value assigned to the global object.

So in my opinion this code is totally wrong :)

Comment: @RachelWillows is this explanation enough for you?